# How to print image on thermal printer

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I try print image on the thermal print:

```
   void Method()
   {
        var printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings() { PrinterName = "zebra" };
        printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument_PrintPage);
        printDocument.Print();
    }

    void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/orderedList6.png")), 0, 0);
    }
```

But document is not printed. Also document visible in the print queue and I can print to the .xps file.

Comment: This might be a problem with the Windows print spooler and not your code. Can you print a word document from this PC?

Comment: Yes, of course. Printer and system are working. Problem in the code.

Comment: Server.MapPath suggests this is ASP.NET. I dont know anything about printing with asp.net but it is likely that this doesnt work out of the box for security reasons.

Comment: I try print from console application. Same story.

Comment: Is your printer's driver name 'zebra' (lower case)?  This library is looking for a printer driver with that exact name.  Lower case 'zebra' is not the default printer driver name, so you will have explicitly changed the driver name to 'zebra' if so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not setting a controller

```
printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create Flowdocument and put your image inside flowdocument's "BlockUIContainer"
- Find the PrintQue by looping through PrintServer
- Use following code to print

```
IDocumentPaginatorSource flowDocument = You_Flowdocument;
var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(Your_printQueue);
DocumentPaginator documentPaginator = flowDocument.DocumentPaginator;
writer.Write(documentPaginator);
```

You can set the label size by using `UserPrintTicket.PageMediaSize` and `Desity` through the thermal printer dll.